# nose plugin for expected-failures

Tags: python, testing, nose

Is there an existing plugin which could be used like:

```
@nose.plugins.expectedfailure
def not_done_yet():
    a = Thingamajig().fancynewthing()
    assert a == "example"
```

If the test fails, it would appear like a skipped test:

```
$ nosetests
...S..
```

..but if it unexpected passes, it would appear similarly to a failure, maybe like:

```
=================================
UNEXPECTED PASS: not_done_yet
---------------------------------
-- >> begin captured stdout << --
Things and etc
...
```

Kind of [like SkipTest](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/plugins/skip.html), but not implemented as an exception which prevents the test from running.

Only thing I can find is [this ticket](http://code.google.com/p/python-nose/issues/detail?id=325) about supporting the `unittest2` expectedFailure decorator (although I'd rather not use unittest2, even if nose supported it)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know about a nose plugin, but you could easily write your own decorator to do that. Here's a simple implementation:

```
import functools
import nose

def expected_failure(test):
    @functools.wraps(test)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            test(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            raise nose.SkipTest
        else:
            raise AssertionError('Failure expected')
    return inner
```

If I run these tests:

```
@expected_failure
def test_not_implemented():
    assert False

@expected_failure
def test_unexpected_success():
    assert True
```

I get the following output from nose:

```
tests.test.test_not_implemented ... SKIP
tests.test.test_unexpected_success ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: tests.test.test_unexpected_success
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\nose-1.1.2-py3.2.egg\nose\case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "G:\Projects\Programming\dt-tools\new-sanbi\tests\test.py", line 16, in inner
    raise AssertionError('Failure expected')
AssertionError: Failure expected

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.016s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: Oh, of course! With a minor tweak so it raises SkipTest when the test fails, that's perfect - thanks \o/

Answer (score 5):

Forgive me if I've misunderstood, but isn't the behavior you desire provided by core python's `unittest` library with the `expectedFailure` decorator, which is—by extension—compatible with `nose`?

For an example of use see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.expectedFailure) and a [post about its implementation](http://pybites.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/unittest-now-with-test-skipping-finally.html).

Comment: Yes that is true, but one of the things I like about nose is the ability to write tests as functions, rather than methods on subclasses as is required by the builtin unittest module (e.g `def test_exampleblah(): pass`)

Comment: If that's the issue then perhaps you'd like [`pytest`](http://pytest.org/latest/contents.html), which is [compatible with `nose`](http://pytest.org/latest/nose.html), also supports [tests as functions](http://pytest.org/latest/assert.html#asserting-with-the-assert-statement) and has the [`xfail`](http://pytest.org/latest/skipping.html#mark-a-test-function-as-expected-to-fail) decorator.

Comment: In my experience, `unittest.expectedFailure` is *not* compatible with Nose. [Nose bug 33](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/issues/33) concurs.

Comment: "not compatible with Nose".  Seems compatible enough to me, in 2018.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with one of two ways:

1. [`nose.tools.raises`](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html#nose.tools.raises) decorator

   ```
   from nose.tools import raises

   @raises(TypeError)
   def test_raises_type_error():
       raise TypeError("This test passes")
   ```
2. `nose.tools.assert_raises`

   ```
   from nose.tools import assert_raises

   def test_raises_type_error():
       with assert_raises(TypeError):
           raise TypeError("This test passes")
   ```

Tests will fail if exception is not raised.

Yup, I know, asked 3 years ago :)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? AFAICT this is the best answer.